# "Problem with position of <title> element in Next.js"

Tags: tags

I am facing an issue with the position of the "<title>" element in Next.js while doing the final build of my application. I've reviewed my code, and the "title" element is defined at the beginning of the  "Head" component, but when inspecting the generated HTML, I noticed that it appears at the end of the header.

Html on crome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntVxV.png)

"Layout" component to wrap "pages"

```
const MainLayout: FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  title,
  description ,
  image ,
}) => {
  const { pathname, locale } = useRouter();
  const pathnameFormatt = pathname === "/" ? "" : pathname;
  return (
    <div className={styles.containerWhite}>
      <Head>
        <title>{title}</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
        <meta name="description" content={description} />
......
```

File "_document.tsx"

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
```

I've considered some basic solutions, such as reviewing the generated HTML code, making sure there are no duplicates of the "Head" component, and disabling certain automatic optimizations in the Next.js settings. However, the problem remains.

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue or could offer some guidance on where to look to fix it.

Comment: That's exactly where it's supposed to be